# Copy specific row into newly created worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I take a range of cells and create worksheets from a template. I plan on using my template to do the work of copying and pasting work items.

I need to also copy and paste a certain row into the new worksheets.

```vb
Sub CreateSheets()
 
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

On Error GoTo Errorhandling

Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select cell range:", _
  Title:="Create sheets", _
  Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
 
For Each cell In rng

    'Check if cell is not empty      
    If cell <> "" Then
 
        'Insert worksheet and name the worksheet based on cell value
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets("Unit Types")

        'Name new sheet based off two cells on Bid Summary List Cells (Bi and Di)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "UNIT-" & cell
    
        'This is where I think I should add the copy/paste lines... but I don't know how.    
        'Copy unit# row and paste in correct worksheet
        Range("XX:XX").Copy Range("XX:XX")
    
    End If

    'Continue with next cell in cell range
Next cell
 
'Go here if an error occurs
Errorhandling:
 
'Stop macro
End Sub
```

In the pictures I show where I want to paste the information. This way I can link the cells to the appropriate areas in the template and run VBA code to delete blank cells.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems that it is clear for you what you intend to do, but it is not clear as question. In order to make it clear, you should show the information: How is the template, how is the input, what is the expected output. With the one you attached it seems that it is a matter to paste by the cell address (row and column). There are some assumptions that you should explain better as which one is the input at the InputBox that you intend in order to make your code working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub CreateSheets()
 
    Dim rng As Range, wsUnitTypes as Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    
    'On Error GoTo Errorhandling 'uncomment this when your code is working...
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsUnitTypes = wb.Sheets("Unit Types")
    
    Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select cell range:", _
                            Title:="Create sheets", _
                            Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
 
    For Each cell In rng.Cells      'loop selected unit#'s
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then 'check if cell is not empty
         
            wb.Sheets("Template").Copy After:= wsUnitTypes
            Set ws = wb.Sheets(wsUnitTypes.Index + 1) 'reference the new sheet
            
            ws.Name = "UNIT-" & cell.Value
            'copy (e.g.) 1x10 range starting at `cell`
            cell.Resize(1, 10).Copy ws.Range("E5")
        End If
    Next cell
 
    Exit Sub 'don't run into the error handler
Errorhandling:
 
End Sub
```

Comment: No this doesn't work for me. Its not creating new worksheets anymore. I'm trying to adapt what you have to my code to see if anything happens.

Comment: Comment out the error handler and see what you get